# Search for a CSS file

Tags: css

A few hours ago I had to change the width and padding on a few divs on [this](http://www.revisionapp.co.uk/t1) page. I messed around with the developer tool of the browser for a few minutes to see what exactly I want to change. After I connected to the ftp I made the changes I thought were necessary, but I nothing happened. After banging my head for half an hour it turns out that I was making the changes to a cached version of the file. I asked the guy who gave me the task where the css file was, but he couldn't answer me.

So how do I find out where the css file is after I log into the ftp server? In this case there were multiple directories with multiple css files.

Comment: you can look in the source for the path where the css file is suppose to be. A Cached version is not saved as a file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the website uses a plugin to cache CSS files, and these cached files shouldn't be edited directly. It looks like the site is running Wordpress, in which case you'll need to look in the wp-content/themes folder (it will depend on which theme you're running where exactly the CSS file is). It's also often possible to edit the CSS directly from within the wordpress admin panel (Appearance > Editor)

Comment: Ok so the actual css was in one of the themes that is used. But there was no effect after I changed it there either. Does this mean that I have found a wrong file or it's something to do with the plugin?

Comment: If you've got a caching plugin, the old, cached CSS may still be being served. Look for an option to reset the cache.